# Using Select By Location in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location

How do you create a new feature class from the select by location tool in python?
This is my script that works but I just don't know what the next step is.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Buildings", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", "Hydrography", "50 feet", "NEW_SELECTION","NOT_INVERT")
```

Comment: can you display the code please? and is this for ArcGIS/arcpy?

Comment: it selects the buildings that are 50 feet from the hydrography but got stuck on how to create a feature class from just the selected features

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 10):

To do this with python you need to create some variables first so you can call the selection and with the arcpy.CopyFeatures tool copy the selection to a new feature class.

```
# Define output feature class location    
fc = "C:\Users\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Testers"
# Define Selection criteria
Selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('Points', "WITHIN", 'Trajectory')
# Define output selection and fc
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Selection, fc)
```

This example was used within the Python interpreter in ArcMap. You can see that by using variables it makes everything easier to use and understand.

The example you provide should be something like this:

```
import arcpy 
#Set geoprocessing environments 
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Student/PythonBasics10_0/Westerville.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 

# Set name of output fc and select buildings by location
Outputfc =  "BuildingsWithin50ft"
Selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Buildings", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", "Hydrography", "50 feet", "NEW_SELECTION","NOT_INVERT") 

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Selection, Outputfc)
```

Comment: ok let me try it and see what iget

Comment: have a look at the answer above...I think you need to understand that variables are fed into the functions so I have defined Outputfc a string that will feed through the Copyfeatures function to create a fc called "BuildingsWithin50ft" to the arcpy.env.workspace

Comment: No worries tick the answer as correct if it is correct :-)

Comment: and it is hard to get the hang of it

Comment: You'll get there...it's just practise :-) Good luck!

Comment: spk578's answer worked for me. I'm using it in Pro v. 3.0.3, and or course arcpy's functions have been updated to ```arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation()``` and ```arcpy.management.CopyFeatures()```, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach to creating new fc from selected layer features would be:

1. Define environmental workspace
2. Define two selection fc's to use within select by location method
3. Use [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) method (you will have to use this if performing selections via standalone script, outside of ArcGIS)
4. Use [Select Layer by Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001700000072000000) method
5. Use [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000) method to create new layer from selected features

Comment: why does arcgis require you to create a feature layer to use in the select by location?

Comment: This is required it the code/layer is run in standalone outside of ArcMap so the layer may be selected against.

Comment: yes but why? you can run other standalone tool scripts using the paths to the actual feature class

Comment: When dealing with evaluating intersection between layer feature you have to make it a feature layer.  As far as the why may be an Esri developer can expand more.